# Find the longest chaining list?

Tags: algorithm, list

I have a lot of objects. Some object can produce a chaining list, and all objects have a chaining continuation on condition. A exemple will explain more. Let's say I have this two objects :

```
[
  {
    "name": "ObjectA",
    "produce": "ChainA",
    "continuations": [
      { "ChainB": "ChainC" },
      { "ChainC": "ChainC" }
    ]
  }
  {
    "name": "ObjectB",
    "produce": null,
    "continuations": [
      { "ChainA": "ChainB" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to find the list :

```
ChainA (ObjectA) => ChainB (ObjectB) => ChainC (ObjectA) => ChainC (ObjectA)
```

I just can't find a better way that looping over and over again. Some of you have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Your example made it more complicated. Which chainC, which chainB. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is NP-complete because if you had an efficient algorithm to solve it, then you could solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem.  So it is pretty hopeless.

Here is the reduction.  Given a directed graph `G`, label the edges as objects and label the vertices as chains.  Each "object" (edge) produces the "chain" that is the vertex it goes to.  Each "object" (edge) has a single continuation, from the source "chain" (vertex) to the target "chain" (vertex).

Now apply the hypothetical algorithm.  The longest chaining list will be the edges of the desired longest path for `G`.